# Forwarding Data from COM Port via Ad-hHoc Network on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, serial-port, ad-hoc-network, lubuntu

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to setup an ad-hoc network between two computers in order to send data coming from a COM port on one computer to the other. Currently I'm running Lubuntu 12.04 on both computers.

I've done some research and found that likely I can use socat to accomplish this but I'm unsure of exactly how to set up the connection on both computers so that this is possible.

Additionally, once the connection has been established using socat will the computer that will be receiving the data see the connection as a virtual COM port?